# Delete all index with similary name

Tags: elasticsearch

Hi everyone I have 100 index into my elasticsearch and I want to delete them with one query. They all begin with myindex:

```
myindex-1
myindex-2
myindex-3
myindex-4
  .
  .
  .
myindex-100
```

when I try this query, it does not work:

```
curl -XDELETE http://localhost:9200/myindex*
```

I get:

```
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Wildcard expressions or all indices are not allowed"}],"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Wildcard expressions or all indices are not allowed"},"status":400}
```

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Are you deleting all indices with this wildcard expression delete?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could use The following in kibana dev tool:

```
PUT /_cluster/settings
{
  "transient": {
  "action.destructive_requires_name":false

  }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Elasticsearch [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-delete-index.html) says:

> The delete index API can also be applied to more than one index, by either using a comma separated list, or on all indices (be careful!) by using _all or *as index.
>
> In order to disable allowing to delete indices via wildcards or _all, set action.destructive_requires_namesetting in the config to true. This setting can also be changed via the cluster update settings api.

So this could work if you have a predefined number of indices to delete:

```
curl -XDELETE http://localhost:9200/myindex-1,myindex-2,myindex-3,myindex-4
```

If you want to use wildcards you'll have to update the configuration as stated above

Comment: Just be careful: Wildcards are allowed by default as stated in the quoted documentation (though the sentence is a bit confusing).

Comment: used this technique after being meowed (sad face), after securing my server (happy face)